# Angular Routing with parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to implement an edit button, where it should navigate to the page that is meant to be edited. 
      I know that parameterised Routes should be used, but I am not sure how exactly it should be implemented in relation to this code? 
      could someone please come with a suggestion or links of tutorials that I can solve my problem as well as I want to learn more in depth about Routing in Angular later on. 
      I did read the Angular documentation on Routing, but it didn't help me much.

```
export interface FileModel {
  Id?: Array<string>;
  dbList?: Array<string>;
  name?: string;
}

export interface File {
  fileId?: number;
  name?: string;
  dbList?: string;
}

public editFile: FileModel  = {};

      edit(file: File){
         this.editFile.dbList = file.dbList.split(',');
         this.editFile.name = file.name;

         // navigate and send

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to inject the `Router` in the constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Then in your code where you would like to navigate do something like this:

```
this.router.navigate([`/navigateUrlPart/${file.id}`]);
```

And of course you should create a routing in your `AppRoutingModule` to keep it working together

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    { navigateUrlPart/:id', component: YourEditComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And in the `YourEditComponent` you can read the edited `id` from the route params using the `ActivatedRoute` class